# Sample developer authentication aws cognito shows error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cognito

I have tried sample Develeoper authentication example [here](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-cognito-developer-authentication-sample) at server side used ElasticBeanstalk. But when I try to register  using browser it shows "This site experienced an unexpected error. Please try your request again later". how to solve it?

```
 28-Jan-2016 19:14:51.947 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-6]  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create device table.
at main.java.com.amazonaws.cognito.devauthsample.identity.DeviceAuthentication.<init>(DeviceAuthentication.java:85)
at main.java.com.amazonaws.cognito.devauthsample.identity.AWSCognitoDeveloperAuthenticationSample.<init>(AWSCognitoDeveloperAuthenticationSample.java:46)
at main.java.com.amazonaws.cognito.devauthsample.servlet.RootServlet.init(RootServlet.java:50)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:817)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)Causedby:main.java.com.amazonaws.cognito.devauthsample.exception.DataAcces  sException: Failed to get status of table:       AWSCognitoDeveloperAuthenticationSample_awscognitodeveloperauthenticationsample_DEVICES
at main.java.com.amazonaws.cognito.devauthsample.identity.DeviceAuthentication.doesTableExist(DeviceAuthentication.java:266)
at main.java.com.amazonaws.cognito.devauthsample.identity.DeviceAuthentication.<init>(DeviceAuthentication.java:81)
... 23 more
Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: User: arn:aws:sts::728830372817:assumed-role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role/i-746f13fd is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:DescribeTable on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:728830372817:table/AWSCognitoDeveloperAuthenticationSample_awscognitodeveloperauthenticationsample_DEVICES (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: EOA1PRP4O61T364TFRCF0GP4FRVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1077)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:725)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:460)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:295)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:3106)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.describeTable(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:833)
at main.java.com.amazonaws.cognito.devauthsample.identity.DeviceAuthentication.doesTableExist(DeviceAuthentication.java:261)
... 24 more
```

Comment: Have you checked the server logs?  Is there a detailed message there that you can post?

Comment: I have checked last 100 lines of the log file before and after the registering. No information about the error. However Please see the files [error.jsp](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-cognito-developer-authentication-sample/blob/master/src/main/webapp/jsp/error.jsp) in the link above. and the [RegisterUserServlet.java](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-cognito-developer-authentication-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/cognito/devauthsample/servlet/RegisterUserServlet.java). I found the cause in these two files. But don't know how to solve it

Comment: There has to be a detailed error message that would have been generated when the process was sent to errror.jsp. You need to track that down.

Comment: I have seen a error while uploading and deploying war file? is this a problem?

Answer (score 2):

The error "authorized to perform: dynamodb:DescribeTable on resource:xxx" suggests that the IAM role used by Elastic Beanstalk does not have permission to do "DescribeTable" call. Can you please check the permissions you have given to the IAM role being used here?

Comment: AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess ,AmazonCognitoDeveloperAuthenticatedIdentities, AmazonDynamoDBFullAccesswithDataPipeline these are the three permissions set for Elastc BeanStalk

Comment: Can you please verify the elastic beanstalk app is using this role? If yes and it still doesn't work , can you please try the option 2[1] in the github sample[2]?

[1]https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-cognito-developer-authentication-sample#option-2-build-and-deploy-the-server-application-yourself-using-amazon-elastic-beanstalk
[2]https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-cognito-developer-authentication-sample

Comment: Hi Rachit, thanks, giving AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess solved my problem. But is it recommended to give full access or is there any more secure options I mean only access to create device table?

Comment: We always recommend scoping down the permissions to the minimum you require. In the AWS IAM console you can specify what actions can a user/role can do on a particular resource.

Comment: Venkat, I would encourage you to post your question on stackoverflow or Amazon Cognito Forums.